# how to print irregular file format using awk or shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a statistics file on my Linux server which updates counters named "C1" , "C2_Detected", "C3_Detected" after every 10 seconds. The C2 and C3 counters also have an additional heading on next line (i.e. "Detected") but C1 does not have that. I need to read the values of `C2_Detected` and `C3_detected` and print the output in the format below, when only `C2_detected` and `C3_Detected` are non-zero.

The output shall print: Date, Time, Name and either C2_Detected or C3_Detected value.

For example, at 17:37:41, C3_Detected value is 4, so the output shall be like this.

```
16-06-21 Name            C1    C2        C3
                              detected  detected
17:37:41 monthly_output  319  0         4
```

I have tried `awk` using date (i.e. 16-06-2016) as record separator but it doesn't work.  Please assist how to separate records as each record is multi-line.

Input file format, which repeats after 10 seconds with date as record separator:

```
16-06-21  Name             C1         C2        C3
                                   detected    detected
17:37:41  daily_output      1144      0         0 
          monthly_output     319       0        4
          yearly__output    533       0         0
16-06-21  Name             C1        C2         C3
                                   detected     detected
17:37:41  daily_output       1144        3      0
          monthly_output     319         0      0
          yearly__output    533        0        0
```

Comment: It might help, to format the question, say the file input with leading 4 spaces to have it in a code environment etc. I have trouble understanding where spaces are relevant in your questions in and output and where not, where newlines are and where not. Thanks.

Comment: You're struggling due to the screwy input format but you want to produce similarly screwy output format? Why not output a CSV so you can import into excel or otherwise manipulate it easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

weird but ok:

```
awk '{
  if($2=="Name"){
    date=$1
    start=NR
    first=$0
  }
  else if(start>0){
    if(NR==(start+1)){
      second=$0
    }
    else if(NR==(start+2)){
      time=$1
    }
  }
  if(start>0 && NR>=(start+2) && ($4>0 || $5>0)){
    if(time!=$1){
      $5=$4;$4=$3;$3=$2;$2=$1
    }
    printf "%s\n%s\n%s  %s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", first,second,time,$2,$3,$4,$5
  }
}' testfile

16-06-21  Name             C1         C2        C3
                                   detected    detected
17:37:41  monthly_output    319 0   4
16-06-21  Name             C1        C2         C3
                                   detected     detected
17:37:41  daily_output  1144    3   0
```

Comment: I wonder what the output should look like if two or three of the 'period_output' lines have C2 or C3 greater than 0?  The question doesn't indicate that.

Comment: above code is working fine , can you explain is it necessary to keep if (time ! = $1 ) $5=$4 ......or what's the use of this in code

Comment: sure. if time = $1, then it's a daily output row. $2 = "daily_output", etc... but for monthly and yearly output rows, $1 = "monthly_output" or "yearly_output". all the awk fields are shifted over one. it would also work to instead do: if time != $1 then printf... time,$1,$2,$3,$4 (instead of 2,3,4,5).

Comment: if i want to print heading columns i.e. first and second only once at beginning - how the code will be ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to help you shoot yourself in the foot by producing an output format that's just as hard to parse as your input format. Try this instead:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
/^[0-9-]+[[:space:]]/ {
    date = $1
    names[1] = "Date" OFS "Time"
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        names[i] = $i
    }
    nf = NF
    next
}
NF==2 {
    if (NR==2) {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            names[(nf-NF)+i] = names[(nf-NF)+i] "_" $2
        }
        for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", names[i], (i<nf?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    if (NF==nf) {
        time = $1
    }
    else {
        $0 = time FS $0
    }
    if ( ($NF != 0) || ($(NF-1) != 0) ) {
        $1 = $1
        print date, $0
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Date,Time,Name,C1,C2_detected,C3_detected
16-06-21,17:37:41,monthly_output,319,0,4
16-06-21,17:37:41,daily_output,1144,3,0

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s, -t
Date      Time      Name            C1    C2_detected  C3_detected
16-06-21  17:37:41  monthly_output  319   0            4
16-06-21  17:37:41  daily_output    1144  3            0
```